# Count number of male and female

Tags: sql

i want to count  no of male and female in a table called Gender having entry given below. Answer should be female=2 Male=3 in count.
Is there any query in SQL.

```
Gender
MALE
MaLE
FEMALE
Female
```

Comment: Give us the table please.

Comment: Tell us in which database you want this Oracle, MySql, SqlServer....

Comment: The collation of the column they are stored in would be useful as well.

Comment: Table name is testcount.

Comment: Database is MySql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Male_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female_count
FROM some_unknown_table
```

As nightfox79 mentioned, if your default collation is case sensitive, you probably should transform the text to ensure it would match.
So, use this

```
UPPER(GENDER) = 'MALE'
UPPER(GENDER) = 'FEMALE'
```

Sidenote: I think you should use a tinyint column for Gender following this format, as Damien mentioned. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218

Comment: You should do an upper or lower of Gender, look at his example

Comment: Yeah, i'll add that. I'm so used to Case Insensitive collations. Thanks!

Comment: You suggest to use a `bit` column and then propose to store the value `2` in it? Intriguing idea. I'd usually recommend `tinyint` and using [ISO/IEC 5218](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218) - I.e. why *invent* a new encoding?

Comment: Updated. @Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried if i could insert a 2 on bit and it was successful; didnt check what value was stored. Thanks~

Answer (score 2):

Please try this :-

```
 Select count(CASE WHEN Gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Male_count,
        count(CASE WHEN Gender = 'Female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Female_count
  FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
SUM(Gender = 'Male') as male_count,
SUM(Gender = 'Female') AS female_count
FROM people

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT UPPER([Gender]),count(*)
  FROM [test].[dbo].[TableName] group by UPPER([Gender])
```