# How to count values in an SQLite table using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I would like to know how to use the count function when using sqlite in python to look up and return the number of specific values there are in a table. For example, I want to be able to look in an sqlite table showing students and their characteristics and be able to find how many of them are male or female using python. I have done some research but have only found relevant information for when you are just using sqlite.

Comment: Can you add the code that you've tried ?

Comment: What is your table schema? As it is now this is rather broad. Please consider trying out some tutorials like [this one](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introduction-to-sqlite-in-python/) or [this other one](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/) first, and then either [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17119151/count-male-female-and-total) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43110609/count-number-of-male-and-female) may become useful (note how they are different/schema dependant).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try this :

```
 rowsQuery = "SELECT Count() FROM %s" % table
 cursor.execute(rowsQuery)
 numberOfRows = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

you have to change the rowsQuery according to your need .

For your question:

```
 rowsQuery = "select count(STUDENT) from table_name where Gender= 'Male'"
```

Comment: This is just retrieving data from a table. I want to count the occurrence of a value in a table.

Comment: count of a value that is in a particular column in that table ?

Comment: So you only need to change the query : `select count(primary_key_column) from table_name where Gender= "Male"`

Comment: Please use SQL placeholders instead of building the query with string operations. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3-placeholders